# How to use assocs with HashMap in Haskell

Tags: dictionary, haskell

Currently I'm trying to use the Map's assocs method, but unable to figure out how to get it to work for a HashMap. For a regular Map the following works just fine.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
test = M.fromList [("a", 1), ("b", 2)]
M.assocs test
```

However when I try the same thing with a HashMap it doesn't work. I tried several variation on the import all fail with different errors. Oddly however most other functions that work on maps work just fine with the below import, for example I have no trouble using `M.lookup`.

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as M
test = M.fromList [("a", 1), ("b", 2)]
M.assocs test
```

In case it is useful the above code gives the following error:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    Not in scope: ‘M.assocs’
    No module named ‘M’ is imported.
```

Comment: However it is here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashmap-1.3.3/docs/Data-HashMap.html#v:assocs

Comment: Ah sorrry you use the Lazy version

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yea turns out there is a toLists method in the Lazy version that does the same thing as assocs.

Comment: Strange. I always called this function "toList"'. I thought you were looking for something else.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent is ToList and assocs not the same somehow?

Comment: @Jeffreys It seems like one of them preservers the order. I've seen that somewhere iin the doc. Otherwise indeed this is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer. In Data.HashMap.Lazy the method `toList` performs the same function as `assocs`. As such the following code works.

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as M
test = M.fromList [("a", 1), ("b", 2)]
M.toList test
```

Answer (score 2):

Data.HashMap.Lazy, from unordered-containers, does not export an `assocs` function.

You might be thinking of `Data.HashMap` from the `hashmap` package.

Comment: I tried importing Data.HashMap but that package doesnt appear to exist even though Data.HashMap.Lazy does exist. So I'm still a bit confused as to how exactly I should fix this. I assume the Lazy version is going to be more efficient so do I need to implement my own assocs method that does the exact same thing?

Comment: If you want to import `Data.HashMap` then install the package in which it resides - `cabal install hashmap` (or use your packaging system of choice).  If you want to keep using the modules from unordered-containers, such as `Data.HashMap.{Strict,Lazy}` then you'll need to make your own `assocs` method.  I can't say if the lazy module will be more efficient for you - that depends on the situation.

Comment: So turns out the toList method in the Lazy package does the same thing as assocs. I submited that as my own answer since I feel it more accurately solved the problem then needing to rewrite assocs.